# Rejection in US

Tags: rejection

In reference to the patent: [US20100065236](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100065236)

Why was it rejected in the US?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get specific information about a US patent or application is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. In this case, you get past a CAPTCHA, enter "20100065236", select "document number" and you will find that this application's status is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action". The Transaction History tab lists communications between the inventor's agent and the USPTO. You can order the file wrapper if you don't mind paying something.

Comment: You can get those documents for free. Afaik at the uspto, but if not, use espacenet and klick international dossier

Comment: Usually at Pair too. Just not for this application. I don't know if this is true for all applications vs granted patents or what. If you can find those docs for this application, please feel free to add to my answer or create your own.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have a look later

Comment: https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.46747209.A&lng=en

Comment: I tried PAIR and I can open the documents there too. Maybe there was a bug?